# witch api to use in API Exlore tool to display urls of videos included in a folder in dailymotion

Tags: video

In the API Explorer Tool, I fill the "**Connection user ▸ video (videos)**" paragraph and, in the result, I get this request URL:

> https://api.dailymotion.com/user/i24news-fr/videos?fields=title,url,&created_before=2017%2F11%2F13&sort=recent&limit=10

The resulting list contains, for example, this item:

```
{
  "title": "13 Novembre: commémorations demain en France",
   "url": "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x68vq2r"
}.
```

This URL contains several forms of the same video (`.MP4` and `.ts` with several resolutions):

> 13 Novembre: commémorations demain en France_512x384.mp4
>
> 13 Novembre: commémorations demain en France_512x384.ts
>
> 13 Novembre: commémorations demain en France_320x240.mp4

etc...

How can I include, on the list, the URL's of the ....`512x384.mp4` videos?

Cordially

Answer (score 0):

The API limit 50 call per day so you probably dont wanna use it

```
function curlGet($URL) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 3;
    curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_URL , $URL );
    curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , $timeout );
    $tmp = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $tmp;
}
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $link144=$link240=$link380=$link480=$link720=$link1080='';
    $url= "https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/" . $id;
    $video_info = curlGet($url);
    preg_match('/,"qualities":(.+),"reporting"/', $video_info, $match);
    $jd=json_decode($match[1],1);
    if(@$jd['144']){
        $link144=$jd['144'][1]['url'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately I can only program in Visual Basic and I do not know how to exploit your answer.
I thought it was enough to manually add a parameter to the query generated by the Explorer API and enter it into the internet browser to get my list.
Cordially.